# How can I make this bash script create a file owned by a regular user?

Tags: bash

I have a simple bash program, file structure is:

$ tree

```
.
├── includes
│   └── vimrc.vim
└── test_sourcing_vimrc.sh
```

.

```
file: test_sourcing_vimrc.sh

#! /bin/bash

self_dir=$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )

sudo -s -u lando cat includes/vimrc.vim > test_output
```

.

```
file: includes/vimrc.vim (contains a .vimrc content)

" vim settings

set number
set laststatus=2
syntax enable
```

My intention is to

- run the script as a root user (the script needs these privileges for other reasons) e.g.
  `sudo ./test_sourcing_vimrc.sh`
- `sudo` to a non-root user "lando" - who already exists
- `cat` the contents of `includes/vimrc.vim` into a new file `test_output`
- `test_output` should be owned by "lando" but its owned by root, e.g.
  `-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root     5620 Sep 24 19:00 test_output`

How can I get this script to create a file owned by correct non-root user?

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is:

```
sudo install -o lando -m0775 -p -S includes/vimrc.vm test_output
```

The `-m0775` sets the permissions that the copied file receives; these permissions are actually the default so that can be omitted if they're the ones you want. The `-p` makes the modification time of the copied file be the same as the original. The `-S` makes it that if `test_output` already exists, it doesn't get clobbered unless the `install` has already successfully managed to copy the source file. Depending on your needs, these may be unnecessary. I'm noting them anyway for others who may come across this question and have somewhat different needs.

Finally, since the containing script is already being run as root, you can omit the initial `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

solved

changed

```
sudo -s -u lando cat includes/vimrc.vim > test_output
```

to

```
sudo -s -u lando <<EOF
cat includes/vimrc.vim > test_output
EOF
```

Comment: Or, simply: `sudo -u lando sh -c 'cat includes/vimrc.vim > test_output'`